# SQL Using inner query in left join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, db2

I have the below two tables ONE & TWO

```
ONE           TWO

ID            ID  CODE  
-----         ---------
1             1    1
2             1    2
3             2    1
4             3    1  
5             3    2  
              3    3
```

### Output required

```
ID    CODE  
----------  
1     2  
2     1  
3     3  
4     NULL  
5     NULL
```

I used the below query but it is throwing the error "**An ON clause associated with a JOIN operator or in a MERGE statement is not valid.**"

```
SELECT  A.ID
       ,B.CODE
FROM   ONE A 
LEFT JOIN
       TWO B
ON     A.ID = B.ID
   AND B.CODE = (
                   SELECT 
                         MAX(Z.CODE)
                   FROM TWO Z
                   WHERE Z.ID = A.ID
            )
```

Comment: Oracle does not support using subquery in the Join condition so instead use the query in the table name like the answer i have given below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  A.ID
   ,B.CODE
FROM   ONE A 
LEFT outer JOIN
   (select id,max(code) CODE from two group by id) B
ON     A.ID = B.ID
```

I believe this is what you are looking for....

Comment: You can also use @Gordan answer given, which doesn't need us to execute a subquery...

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a join and aggregation (if I understand the logic correctly):

```
select ONE.id, max(TWO.CODE)
from ONE left outer join
     TWO
     on ONE.id = TWO.id
group by ONE.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged also SQL-Server, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ONE.ID,  TWO.CODE,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ONE.ID ORDER BY TWO.CODE DESC)
    FROM ONE LEFT OUTER JOIN TWO
        ON ONE.ID=TWO.ID
)
SELECT  ID, CODE FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cdba0/1/0)</kbd>